# How to add remote in Git GUI?

Tags: git

I am new to the git. I have two computers connected in network. On first computer i have remote repository in some location like 'C:\Test\Test1.git'. Now i want to add this remote repository in my another computer which is connected in netowrk.

while adding i do this

[image]

It gets added. No error occurs in here.

But when i try to fetch from this. i get error like this

**ssh: C: no address associated with name**

**fatal: Could not read from remote repositor**

what to do now???

well m new to this?? is there any better option?

Comment: That URL does not look like a valid location URL.

Comment: Which transfer protocol (ssh, http, smb, ...) do you want to use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**note: my setup is using windows.**

but when i setup my shares i create LAN only network names in:

`\\computer_name\share_name\` format

but git will not recognize these names, so you need to invert the slashes.

`//computer_name/share_name/` format

so if the machine is called `git_server` and the share name is `repos` and the actual git repository is called `test.git` (yes, the actual folder name has .git at the end). i would clone this repo as such:

`git clone //git_server/repos/test.git`

this will clone your repo and allow you to push and pull from it.

**important note!**

you will only be able to push if it's a `bare` git repo. so when you create your repo make sure to use: `git init --bare`

---

i did a bit more research, and if that's still not working the git supports the windows `file:///` naming convention

so

`git clone file:///git_server/repos/test.git`

or

`git clone file:///\\git_server\repos\test.git`

should both work as well